# How add a image (frame) in other image using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image

I am wanting to add a frame to an image using Laravel.
Example, I have two images, one image is the png frame, and the other is the original image.

I need to put the two together to form an image with a frame.

This is my frame.

My goal is that I can put a frame on any image.

Comment: Okay, so one option is simply to place the border image over the top of the "original" image in e.g. CSS. Another option is to use an image manipulation library like Imagick to generate a composite of the two images.

Comment: This is more of an html/css question as opposed to Laravel. But since we're talking about Laravel, I would create a blank view (or div, which ever works) and set the background property in the css to the image frame. Then in another div, set the z-index to a negative number to put it "behind" the frame and echo the path to an image that you want. If you set the background-image property to a z-index of let's say 10, then the image to -1, the image will always appear behind the frame. This is all css/html though, nothing php or laravel specific.

Comment: @maximus1127 It's *possible* OP needs this done server-side.

Comment: true. but that wasn't necessarily specified and given the nature of all the answers so far, i think everyone is approaching this from a client side solution standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily compose images together using JavaScript with [merge-image](https://github.com/lukechilds/merge-images) package.

With the following images:

- `/body.png`

[image]

- `/eyes.png`

[image]

- `/mouth.png`

[image]

You can do:

```js
import mergeImages from 'merge-images';

mergeImages(['/body.png', '/eyes.png', '/mouth.png'])
  .then(b64 => document.querySelector('img').src = b64);
  // data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...
```

And that would update the `img` element to show this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well this is more about the css and html question 
 BTW you can do this in border-image property in css here the example 
**Html**

```
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1565013161635-98472edee347?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" width="50%" id="borderimg1">
```

**CSS**

```
#borderimg1 { 
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
  -o-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
  border-image: url(border.png) 30 round;
}

**Result**
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are some excellent client-side approaches already in this thread, but if you want to do this server-side, [the popular Intervention Image package](http://image.intervention.io/) is handy and designed to work with Laravel.

You'll have to do some resizing math if your images vary in size, but fundamentally you want the [`insert` method](http://image.intervention.io/api/insert) to overlay one over the other.

```
// create new Intervention Image
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// paste another image
$img->insert('public/bar.png');

// create a new Image instance for inserting
$watermark = Image::make('public/watermark.png');
$img->insert($watermark, 'center');

// insert watermark at bottom-right corner with 10px offset
$img->insert('public/watermark.png', 'bottom-right', 10, 10);
```